# How do we do Batch Inferencing on Azure ML Service with Parameterized Dataset/DataPath input?

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

The ParallelRunStep Documentation suggests the following:

A named input Dataset (`DatasetConsumptionConfig` class)

```
path_on_datastore = iris_data.path('iris/')
input_iris_ds = Dataset.Tabular.from_delimited_files(path=path_on_datastore, validate=False)
named_iris_ds = input_iris_ds.as_named_input(iris_ds_name)
```

Which is just passed as an Input:

```
distributed_csv_iris_step = ParallelRunStep(
    name='example-iris',
    inputs=[named_iris_ds],
    output=output_folder,
    parallel_run_config=parallel_run_config,
    arguments=['--model_name', 'iris-prs'],
    allow_reuse=False
)
```

The Documentation to submit Dataset Inputs as Parameters suggests the following:
The Input is a `DatasetConsumptionConfig` class element

```
tabular_dataset = Dataset.Tabular.from_delimited_files('https://dprepdata.blob.core.windows.net/demo/Titanic.csv')
tabular_pipeline_param = PipelineParameter(name="tabular_ds_param", default_value=tabular_dataset)
tabular_ds_consumption = DatasetConsumptionConfig("tabular_dataset", tabular_pipeline_param)
```

Which is passed in `arguments` as well in `inputs`

```
train_step = PythonScriptStep(
    name="train_step",
    script_name="train_with_dataset.py",
    arguments=["--param2", tabular_ds_consumption],
    inputs=[tabular_ds_consumption],
    compute_target=compute_target,
    source_directory=source_directory)
```

While submitting with new parameter we create a new `Dataset` class:

```
iris_tabular_ds = Dataset.Tabular.from_delimited_files('some_link')
```

And submit it like this:

```
pipeline_run_with_params = experiment.submit(pipeline, pipeline_parameters={'tabular_ds_param': iris_tabular_ds})
```

However, how do we combine this: How do we pass a Dataset Input as a Parameter to the ParallelRunStep?

If we create a `DatasetConsumptionConfig` class element like so:

```
tabular_dataset = Dataset.Tabular.from_delimited_files('https://dprepdata.blob.core.windows.net/demo/Titanic.csv')
tabular_pipeline_param = PipelineParameter(name="tabular_ds_param", default_value=tabular_dataset)
tabular_ds_consumption = DatasetConsumptionConfig("tabular_dataset", tabular_pipeline_param)
```

And pass it as an argument in the ParallelRunStep, it will throw an error.

References:

1. [Notebook with Dataset Input Parameter](https://github.com/Azure/MachineLearningNotebooks/blob/master/how-to-use-azureml/machine-learning-pipelines/intro-to-pipelines/aml-pipelines-showcasing-dataset-and-pipelineparameter.ipynb)
2. [ParallelRunStep Notebook](https://github.com/Azure/MachineLearningNotebooks/blob/master/how-to-use-azureml/machine-learning-pipelines/parallel-run/tabular-dataset-inference-iris.ipynb)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the inputs we create Dataset class instances:

```
tabular_ds1 = Dataset.Tabular.from_delimited_files('some_link')
tabular_ds2 = Dataset.Tabular.from_delimited_files('some_link')
```

ParallelRunStep produces an output file, we use the PipelineData class to create a folder which will store this output:

```
from azureml.pipeline.core import Pipeline, PipelineData

output_dir = PipelineData(name="inferences", datastore=def_data_store)
```

The ParallelRunStep depends on ParallelRunConfig Class to include details about the environment, entry script, output file name and other necessary definitions:

```
from azureml.pipeline.core import PipelineParameter
from azureml.pipeline.steps import ParallelRunStep, ParallelRunConfig

parallel_run_config = ParallelRunConfig(
    source_directory=scripts_folder,
    entry_script=script_file,
    mini_batch_size=PipelineParameter(name="batch_size_param", default_value="5"),
    error_threshold=10,
    output_action="append_row",
    append_row_file_name="mnist_outputs.txt",
    environment=batch_env,
    compute_target=compute_target,
    process_count_per_node=PipelineParameter(name="process_count_param", default_value=2),
    node_count=2
)
```

The input to ParallelRunStep is created using the following code

```
tabular_pipeline_param = PipelineParameter(name="tabular_ds_param", default_value=tabular_ds1)
tabular_ds_consumption = DatasetConsumptionConfig("tabular_dataset", tabular_pipeline_param)
```

The PipelineParameter helps us run the pipeline for different datasets.
ParallelRunStep consumes this as an input:

```
parallelrun_step = ParallelRunStep(
    name="some-name",
    parallel_run_config=parallel_run_config,
    inputs=[ tabular_ds_consumption ],
    output=output_dir,
    allow_reuse=False
)
```

To consume with another dataset:

```
pipeline_run_2 = experiment.submit(pipeline, 
                                   pipeline_parameters={"tabular_ds_param": tabular_ds2}
)
```

There is an error currently: [DatasetConsumptionConfig and PipelineParameter cannot be reused](https://github.com/Azure/MachineLearningNotebooks/issues/1312)

Answer (score 0):

AML ParallelRunStep GA is a managed solution to scale up and out large ML workload, including batch inference, training and large data processing. Please check out below documents for the details.

•   [Overview doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/tutorial-pipeline-batch-scoring-classification): run batch inference using ParallelRunStep

•   [Sample notebooks](https://github.com/Azure/MachineLearningNotebooks/tree/master/how-to-use-azureml/machine-learning-pipelines/parallel-run)

•   AI Show: [How to do Batch Inference using AML ParallelRunStep](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/AI-Show/How-to-do-Batch-Inference-using-AML-ParallelRunStep)

•   Blog: [Batch Inference in Azure Machine Learning](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-ai/batch-inference-in-azure-machine-learning/ba-p/1417010)